# Create a symlink that can't be deleted by any users

Tags: linux, unix, symlink

Is it possible to create a symlink that cannot be deleted? It is my understanding all symlinks have 777 permissions and those cannot be modified.

I want 777 permissions on what the symlink is pointing too, and I want the symlink to be undeletable

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Symlinks are files.
Therefore the key to their deletion lies in their containing folder.

`+ data - rwxrwxrwx
-- file1 rwxrwxrwx
-- file2 rwxrwxrwx
+ work - r-xr-xr-x
-- data -> ../data - rwxrwxrwx`

you could do it like that:

`mkdir container
 cd container
 ln -s /path/to/your/data symlink
 cd ..
 sudo chmod a-w container`

Be aware that this also prevents anyone from creating and deleting files in container.

Also the folowing is prevented:
`rm -r container`